# GeoPandas reprojection from 4326 to 3857 not working properly

Tags: python, gis, geopandas

I'm having a bit of trouble with projecting a DataFrame in GeoPandas from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857 in a notebook. My original dataset looks like this:

```
0       POLYGON ((-97.44573128938707 25.889635, -97.35...
1       POLYGON ((-97.61263173798922 25.995165, -97.57...
2       POLYGON ((-97.583158 25.96192090708935, -97.58...
3       POLYGON ((-97.461286 25.89270423248976, -97.46...
4       POLYGON ((-97.33941 25.926101719766, -97.33941...
                              ...                        
4971    POLYGON ((-102.906172 36.475082, -102.906172 3...
4972    POLYGON ((-102.772786 36.481234, -102.772786 3...
4973    POLYGON ((-102.639385 36.48728000000001, -102....
4974    POLYGON ((-102.50597 36.49322100000001, -102.5...
4975    POLYGON ((-102.37254 36.499056, -102.37254 36....
Name: geometry, Length: 4976, dtype: object
```

visualized:

[image: Map version of data]

When I attempt to reproject this to EPSG:3857:

```
reprojected = texas.to_crs(epsg=3857)
```

I'm getting some huge numbers as an output (which obviously aren't correct coordinates):

```
0       POLYGON ((-10847609.18711273 2985418.174237921...
1       POLYGON ((-10866188.46006429 2998482.12034216,...
2       POLYGON ((-10862907.45855956 2994365.44865411,...
3       POLYGON ((-10849340.7295776 2985797.960665139,...
4       POLYGON ((-10835773.55531768 2989931.200110516...
                              ...                        
4971    POLYGON ((-11455462.66652503 4366190.37784271,...
4972    POLYGON ((-11440614.20492607 4367042.077273317...
4973    POLYGON ((-11425764.07353476 4367879.167666097...
4974    POLYGON ((-11410912.38367058 4368701.784074328...
4975    POLYGON ((-11396059.02401403 4369509.784691155...
Name: geometry, Length: 4976, dtype: object
```

Any ideas as to why such a simple reprojection wouldn't be working correctly? I've tried using various forms of the `to_crs` function including `texas.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3857'})` and have triple checked that `texas.crs` is set to `{'init': 'epsg:4326'}`.

For reference I'm using GeoPandas 0.5.1 and PyProj 2.3.1. *Edit:* I've also tried upgrading to GeoPandas 0.6 just for funsies, but no dice :(.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this might have something with the projected bounds. if you look at the example [here](http://geopandas.org/gallery/plotting_basemap_background.html#sphx-glr-gallery-plotting-basemap-background-py), which also got huge numbers on both of the axes.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58033/what-does-projected-bounds-and-wgs84-bounds-mean-in-the-definition-of-a-crs

Comment: According to https://epsg.io, 3857 is *pseudo mercator* and has bounds as large as -20026376.39 to 20026376.39  in x and -20048966.10 to 20048966.10 in y. So your values do not look so stupid...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think those numbers are correct. If you take a look at this site (https://epsg.io/3857) you see that your values are in the projected bounds.

Comment: Yikes yeah! Can't believe I missed that. I think the confusion is coming from Mapbox (the target for this dataset) claiming to use EPSG:3857 but their JS API is seemingly okay with ESPG:4326 coordinates (ie ones that are not huge numbers like in 3857)...